# Dixon's Theorem to probabilistically bound largest factor of N

Tags: probability, number-theory, reference-request

I have recently decided to read up on the current integer factorization algorithms. When looking into some of the algorithms, I came across the following statement:

> Say that p is the smallest prime factor of n. By Dixon's Theorem, the probability that the largest factor of n is less than $(p)^\epsilon$ is roughly $\epsilon ^ {- \epsilon}$.

But when I hear Dixon's Theorem, I think of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_theorem). I currently don't see how Dixon's Theorem yields such a probabilistic bound. Can you help me with that?

And the disclaimer - I am not currently in any class, so this was not assigned to me, it is not a homework problem, and I will in no way be receiving any sort of academic credit for this work.

Comment: Congrats on the 10K :-)

Comment: Maybe they meant <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function">The Dickman function</a>?  In the applications section, it basically gives your result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong Dixon! Please look at [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_factorization_method) to get a start.  Unfortunately, the relevant original paper (Mathematics of Computation 36, 1981, pp 255-260) is behind a pay wall unless you are at a subscribing university.

Comment: [The AMS offers it for free](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090%2FS0025-5718-1981-0595059-1).

Comment: I wasn't able to find the exact statement, could you link the page number from the paper?

Comment: @AshokArora If for some reason you didn't find exact statement in Wikipedia [linked in this answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_factorization_method) then look at section Optimizations, [here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smbbh.png) where statement is located.